# How to price the Definition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Task:
Let V and W be a vector space upon “array” F. Prove that the transformation f:V->W is linear when for every vector v,w from V and for every constant c, d from F the following is true:
f(c*v + d*w) = c*f(v) + d*f(w).

Well from the definition I know that f(v+w) is equal to f(v) + f(w) and also f(c*v) is the equivalent to c*f(v). But what way is one supposed to prove something that is given and is stated?

Thank you for any comments!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by " f(cv) is the equivalent to cf(v)"

Comment: In all books or online definitions of a linear transformation is “f(c*v) = c* f(v)” v is a vector and c is a constant, just like stated in the task.

Comment: I thought you meant something other than $f(cv) = cf(v)$ because you *italicized* "equivalent".

Comment: In any case, the point of the exercise is as follows: show that if $f(cv + dw) = cf(v) + df(w)$, then show that $f$ must satisfy the definition of linearity.  That is, show that $f(v+w) = f(v) + f(w)$ and that $f(cv) = cf(v)$.

Comment: You might want to look at [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) for typing math on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to prove the equivalence between 
$$\begin{align}
(1) & \quad f \textrm{ is linear} \\
(2) & \quad f(cv+dw) = cf(v) + df(w) 
\end{align}$$
where $(1)$ is just an abbreviation for
$$f(v+w) = f(v) + f(w) \ \& \ f(cv) = cf(v). \tag{$*$}$$
So, you need to prove that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ and that $(2)$ implies $(1)$. Let me help you with the last one. So, suppose $(2)$ holds for **every** pair of vectors $v$ and $w$, and for **every** scalars $c$ and $d$.

Then, in particular, for $c=d=1$ we have
$$\begin{align} f(v+w) &= f(1v+1w) \\
&= 1f(v) + 1f(w) \\
&= f(v) + f(w) \end{align}$$
and for $d = 0$, 
$$\begin{align} f(cv) 
&= f(cv + 0w) \\
&= cf(v) + 0f(w) \\
&= cf(v) \end{align}$$
meaning that $(*)$ also holds. Hence $f$ in linear, and therefore, $(2)$ implies $(1)$.

Can you see why $(1)$ implies $(2)$ is more easy?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the statement holds for all vectors $v,w$ and constants $c,d$.  It must therefore hold in the particular cases that

- $c = d = 1$
- $d = 0$, $w = 0$.